# LAG functions and NULLS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

How can I tell the LAG function to get the last "not null" value?

For example, see my table bellow where I have a few NULL values on column B and C.
I'd like to fill the nulls with the last non-null value. I tried to do that by using the LAG function, like so:

```
case when B is null then lag (B) over (order by idx) else B end as B,
```

but that doesn't quite work when I have two or more nulls in a row (see the NULL value on column C row 3 - I'd like it to be 0.50 as the original).

Any idea how can I achieve that?
(it doesn't  have to be using the LAG function, any other ideas are welcome)

A few assumptions:

- The number of rows is dynamic;
- The first value will always be non-null;
- Once I have a NULL, is NULL all up to the end - so I want to fill it with the latest value.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Itzik Ben-Gan wrote a blog on a that problem: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/how-previous-and-next-condition. Unfortunatley SQL Server doesn't support the `IGNORE NULLS` option in `LAST_VALUE`, then it's simple: `LAST_VALUE(B IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY idx)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is null all the way up to the end then can take a short cut

```
declare @b varchar(20) = (select top 1 b from table where b is not null order by id desc);
declare @c varchar(20) = (select top 1 c from table where c is not null order by id desc); 
select is, isnull(b,@b) as b, insull(c,@c) as c 
from table;
```

Comment: good aproach, I didn't want to declare variables so I ended up doing something like:
case when B is null then (select top 1 B from <my_query> where B is not null order by idx desc) else B end as B

great Idea, thanks very much

Comment: I think variable are cleaner to read and it assures you that the query optimizer only does it once.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with `outer apply` operator:

```
select t.id,
       t1.colA,
       t2.colB,
       t3.colC 
from table t
outer apply(select top 1 colA from table where id <= t.id and colA is not null order by id desc) t1
outer apply(select top 1 colB from table where id <= t.id and colB is not null order by id desc) t2
outer apply(select top 1 colC from table where id <= t.id and colC is not null order by id desc) t3;
```

This will work, regardless of the number of nulls or null "islands". You may have values, then nulls, then again values, again nulls. It will still work.

---

If, however the assumption (in your question) holds:

> Once I have a `NULL`, is `NULL` all up to the end - so I want to fill it with the latest value.

there is a more efficient solution. We only need to find the latest (when ordered by `idx`) values. Modifying the above query, removing the `where id <= t.id` from the subqueries:

```
select t.id,
       colA = coalesce(t.colA, t1.colA),
       colB = coalesce(t.colB, t2.colB),
       colC = coalesce(t.colC, t3.colC) 
from table t
outer apply (select top 1 colA from table 
             where colA is not null order by id desc) t1
outer apply (select top 1 colB from table 
             where colB is not null order by id desc) t2
outer apply (select top 1 colC from table 
             where colC is not null order by id desc) t3;
```

Comment: hey, thanks, but as I said, "The number of rows is dynamic" so how would that work with 5 rows?

Comment: @diego - This will work regardless of the number of rows...  But it would have a potentially exponential cost as the data set grows *(the cost of each sub query is higher for the 1000th row than it is for the 999th row)*, but it's certainly tidy for small data-sets.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Yes, you are right. I hadn't read the question carefully.

Comment: of course, I misread your query. It does seem to work, +1 thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

You could make a change to your `ORDER BY`, to force the NULLs to be first in your ordering, but that may be expensive...

```
lag(B) over (order by CASE WHEN B IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE idx END)
```

Or, use a sub-query to calculate the replacement value once.  Possibly less expensive on larger sets, but very clunky.
- Relies on all the NULLs coming at the end
- The LAG doesn't rely on that

```
COALESCE(
    B,
    (
        SELECT
            sorted_not_null.B
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                table.B,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY table.idx DESC)   AS row_id
            FROM
                table
            WHERE
                table.B IS NOT NULL
        )
           sorted_not_null
        WHERE
           sorted_not_null.row_id = 1
    )
)
```

*(This should be faster on larger data-sets, than `LAG` or using `OUTER APPLY` with correlated sub-queries, simply because the value is calculated once.  For tidiness, you could calculate and store the [last_known_value] for each column in variables, then just use `COALESCE(A, @last_known_A), COALESCE(B, @last_known_B), etc`)*

Comment: +1 that does seem to work but my "table" is actually a big query that I don't really want to run more than once, which your solution would require. Thanks very much for the help

Comment: @Diego - other than using LAG, every other answer here (and every approach I can think of) is going to have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select max(diff) from(
Select 
    Case when lag(a) over (order by b) is not null
    Then (a -lag(a) over (order by b)) end as diff 
     From <tbl_name> where
    <relevant conditions>
    Order by b) k
```

Works fine in db visualizer.

Answer (score -3):

```
UPDATE table 
SET B = (@n := COALESCE(B , @n))
WHERE B is null;
```

Comment: This question is about `SQL Server`.

Comment: Right idea, but that's the MySQL notation.  It *can* be done in SQL server, but not quite written that way.

Comment: UPDATE table 
SET B =(select last_value(B ignore nulls) over (order by idx) b from table) where B is null;

Comment: @Adesh - Even that is not SQL Server syntax unfortunately.  SQL Server does not support `IGNORE NULLS`.

Comment: if IGNORE NULLS not work then you can add NULL condition in where clause